# Two same values for 2 different registers - minimalmodbus

Tags: python, modbus, rs485, minimalmodbus

I have started to work with minimal modbus with an AcuRev 2000 whose register map is in this link https://www.accuenergy.com/support/modbus-map/?modbus-map=acurev-2000-modbus-map, I am reading frequency (8192-8193) and voltage in line 2 (8196-8197).

When running my program it usually gives me identical values in those two parameters, I tried some things like increasing the time between readings, or a small delay between them, but it does not seem to improve. What do you think is the problem — could it be the RS-485 adapter?

The output is this and some recurrences are the same as the voltage line, which is the problem:

```
2021-2-24-16:57:41 60.021095275878906 127.21097564697266
2021-2-24-16:57:44 127.1023178100586 127.09758758544922
2021-2-24-16:57:47 60.021095275878906 127.18592071533203
2021-2-24-16:57:50 127.1960220336914 127.19416046142578
2021-2-24-16:57:54 127.1761474609375 127.17230224609375
2021-2-24-16:57:57 59.97891616821289 127.0765609741211
2021-2-24-16:58:0 59.97891616821289 126.90221405029297
```

My code is something like this

```
import minimalmodbus #importamos la libreria
import time
import csv
#declaramos el instrumento
print("Respalda el archivo CSV anterior antes de seguir con el programa")
print("Si ingresas mal los datos puede entrar en un bucle infinito usa ctr+c")
print("Ingrese Puerto de conexion (windows= COMX)")
PORT=input()
print("Cuando desees parar los registros usa ctr+c y una Y para que se guarde el archivo, de otra forma se eliminará")
print("Si no aparece inmediatamente la opcion de salir despues de ctr+c espera unos segundos max(30)")
print("ingrese ID de dispositivo")
ID=int(input())
instr = minimalmodbus.Instrument(PORT, ID) #puerto COM10 de conexion y ID dispositivo
instr.serial.baudrate=9600 #modificamos el baud rate
Cabecera=('Tiempo','Frecuencia','Tensión L2')#cual es el nombre de nuestros datos
with open('Datos.csv','w',newline='') as archivocsv:
    archivo=csv.writer(archivocsv)
    archivo.writerow(Cabecera)
    a=0
    while 1:
        try:
            c=0
            b=0
            tiempo=time.localtime()
            c=instr.read_float(8196, 3,2,0)#leemos un registro flotante
            time.sleep(0.01)
            b=instr.read_float(8192, 3,2,0)#leemos un registro flotante
            Timestamp=str(tiempo.tm_year)+"-"+str(tiempo.tm_mon)+"-"+str(tiempo.tm_mday)+"-"+str(tiempo.tm_hour)+":"+str(tiempo.tm_min)+":"+str(tiempo.tm_sec)
            print(Timestamp,b,c)
            DA=[Timestamp,b,c]
            archivo.writerow(DA)
            a=a+1
            time.sleep(30)
        except IOError:
            a=a
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Desea Salir? Y/N")
            valor=input()
            if valor=="Y":
                print("Se hicieron "+str(a)+" registros correctos")
                print("guarde su documento en otra ubicacion")
                break
            else:
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a 16bit word order problem, an Endianness problem.

The library you use assumes that 16bit words are read in the opposite order to how they are actually read, I don't know if that library allows 16bit words to be swaped when 32bit types are read.

This occurs because Modbus does not define how 32bit types are read and some manufacturers send the high word at the beginning and others do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this error to not appear, I used a delay time between the errors cached, I also changed the order of the records , and the program started to read correctly, however I think it is not a complete solution, because if you start waiting between errors you can have a delay of several seconds in the measurement, and if what you want is to be measurements without delay, it could cause problems as time goes by.

```
with open('Datos.csv','w',newline='') as archivocsv:
    archivo=csv.writer(archivocsv)
    archivo.writerow(Cabecera)
    a=0
    while 1:#tiempo, frecuencia, voltaje
        try:
            c=0
            b=0
            tiempo=time.localtime()
            b=instr.read_float(8192, 3,2,0)#leemos un registro flotante
            time.sleep(0.01)
            c=instr.read_float(8196, 3,2,0)#leemos un registro flotante
            Timestamp=str(tiempo.tm_year)+"-"+str(tiempo.tm_mon)+"-"+str(tiempo.tm_mday)+"-"+str(tiempo.tm_hour)+":"+str(tiempo.tm_min)+":"+str(tiempo.tm_sec)
            print(Timestamp,b,c)
            DA=[Timestamp,b,c]
            archivo.writerow(DA)
            a=a+1
            time.sleep(3)
        except IOError:
            a=a
            time.sleep(0.5)  ***#here is the modification that help***
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Desea Salir? Y/N")
            valor=input()
            if valor=="Y":
                print("Se hicieron "+str(a)+" registros correctos")
                print("guarde su documento en otra ubicacion")
                break
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: An alternative would be to read all of the relevant registers in one transaction (e.g. `read_registers(8192, 6, functioncode=3)`) but then you would need to handle the conversion to a float yourself (this is the approach I use with accuenergy meters); this may be simpler with [pymodbus](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/modbus_payload.html).